# My React Native android and iOS application initially showing blank white screen in 5 to 10 secs

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, web

Always getting white blank screen when running the app on the physical device in android case. Using react-native-navigation can't able to detect the bug please help!

I have created a fresh react-native project and integrated the react-native-navigation library into it and when I am running the app in my physical device by running the command yarn run android it runs but shows blank white screen in android. Once it runs successfully but now it won't.

Comment: maybe you can show your code here

Comment: @FakhriKhairi what type of code you are expecting